# change shape of labels scatterplot R

Tags: r, scatter-plot

I was trying to write some simple script for generating the scatter plots in R.

Here is the code:

```
covData<-read.table("C:/Users/JasonShi/Desktop/all_new_graphs/average_BRCA1.summary",header=TRUE, sep="\t")
exon=covData[,1]
min=covData[,2]
plot(exon,min,main="My Table",las=2)
par(pch=15,col="green")
```

I just want to use pch to change the labels, but it didn't work out when I add it to plot like:

```
plot(exon,min,main="My Table",las=2,pch=15)
```

And this way doesn't work either...

It gives me dashes by default, and seems like I can't make any change to it.

Here is how my data look like(delimited by tab):

Sample_ID   Number
sample_1   6
sample_2   9
sample_3   123

and I wrote simple command as:

```
plot(cov~sample,pch=2,main="My Table",las=2,cex=2)
```

Is it the correct way of generating scatter plots? I have the problem of not able to change pch() value.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you trying to change the point shape on a scatterplot?

Comment: yea..like those dots in the graph..

Comment: "those dots in the graph"? What graph? (And how can you expect `par()` to have any effect on a graphic that has already been written?

Comment: I was trying to generate the scatter plots, just wanted to change labels which is supposed to be pch(). But I don't know how it didn't work. :(

Comment: Are you able to replicate this using a data set accessible to the rest of us? Something simple like the following does change the point type to a solid filled square. 
a <- 1:10; b <- 10:1; plot(x = a, y = b, main = "My Table", pch=15)